# How to code some strings to numbers across all columns in a pandas data frame? For example changing "yes" to 1 in the entire data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I normally use the following code to encode strings to numbers within a specific columns:

```
data['column name'] = data['column name'].map({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})
```

How do we replace all 'Yes' to 1 and 'No' to 0 in the whole data frame without having to write the above code for every column.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a for loop to iterate through all the columns:

```
for column in df.columns():
    data[column] = data[column].map({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})
```

Or use the `replace` method:

```
data = data.replace({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean this:

```
data = data.replace({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})
```

This will replace the values in the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
data = data.apply(lambda x :x.map({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0}))
```